# Remote deployment of a script on linux

Tags: bash, scripting, openldap, deployment, remote

We are creating a lab and wanted to setup like 10-15 hosts with ldap. We need to install on each computer some packages that are necessary to run ldap, so my question is - can I somehow run 1 bash script on multiple computers simultaneously? So basically i have the script on one of my servers and want to run it on 10 machines. Would it be possible?

Comment: Hi Pakuss, [have a look at ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_getting_started.html)

Comment: Take your pick of [any configuration management solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software). We don't do recommendations here.

Answer (score 0):

> can I somehow run 1 bash script on multiple computers simultaneously

Yes

> Would it be possible?

Yes.

I would likely use [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) for this job but there are other configration management tools that you could use.